# XPATH search for Selenium Testing in JAVA

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

The problem that I am facing is that I can't seem to select that div class using XPath.

```
<div class="_3WZoe"><span dir="auto" class="">We can not found, try again.</span></div>
```

How can i do XPath, i don't know.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//div[contains(@class,"_3WZoe")]`